# Unable to create Kinesis Client in Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I have created a Lambda function which is triggered by a DynamoDB stream. I am trying to process Dynamodb events and put them into a Kinesis stream after some transformation. The Lambda has full access to both DynamoDB and Kinesis stream. 
I am using Cloudwatch to check the logs and can see that the DynamoDb events are successfully processed. But when I try to create the Kinesis client (present in a different class), the code fails. I tried logging the error and even printing it but it did not help. Sometimes the logs end with this message

`END RequestId: {some request id}`

Other times, I get the following error

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient).`

The code fails at the time of creation of Kinesis client. I can see the log messages / print statements before the creation of Kinesis client. But right at that line code fails. I am not sure what the problem is. Can someone please help me out?

Here is the class in which the code fails

```
private  AmazonKinesis kinesisClient;
private String streamName;

    public TestKinesisPut(String streamName) {
        this.streamName = streamName;

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS_KEY", "SECRET_KEY");

        System.out.println("aws creds are: " + awsCreds);
        clientBuilder = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).
                withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds));
        System.out.println("Credentials are set: \n " + clientBuilder);

        try {
            System.out.println("This one is new \n About to build new kinesis client");

            // the code fails after this line
            kinesisClient = clientBuilder.build();

        System.out.println("failed to build client");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("failed to initialize producer: " + e.getMessage());
            kinesisClient = null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of head scratching I decided to tinker with the configuration of my Lambda function. Looks like the problem was caused by `OutOfMemoryError`. I increased the memory of my Lambda function and it started working.

It seems that at the time of creation of the KinesisClient, the JVM was getting out of metaspace. I did some research and found this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342418/outofmemoryerror-when-creating-amazons3client-in-lambda/38918849). Please refer the link to view a detailed discussion on a similar scenario.